# Geometry problem for circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Any tips how to proceed?
It's for sure that Ac is the radius but what next?

Comment: Well, not only AC, but also AB and BC are radiuses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* $AC=AB=BC$, hence $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: AB and BC are also radii.

Answer (score 3):

Since the circles have the same radius,
$$ AC = AB = \text{radius of circle 1} = \text{radius of circle 2} = CA = CB $$

Now consider the triangle $ ACB$.

Comment: No need to say "Assuming"! They *have* the same radius.

Comment: I thought of that, and that's quite obvious from the figure and the fact that nothing is said about it - but then...there's always an element of doubt. I mean, that was typed just like that. I'll edit it if you say :D

Comment: I agree one can't assume anything from a figure. But we are told that $A$ and $C$ are the centers, so $\overline{AC}$ is a radius of both circles. :)

Comment: Ah damn! That I didn't even think. Removing the strikethrough too. Thanks for pointing it out